# Как узнать размера массива JSON в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, триггер

Мне необходимо в триггере узнать размер массива JSON,но я не знаю как узнать её,знаю что можно так

```
INSERT INTO new_table SET new_tablecol = NEW.content->'$[0]';
```

Но как именно размер узнать?

Answer (score 1):

Для подсчёта количества есть функция [JSON_LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-length). У вас должен быть mysql версии не ниже 5.7, т.к. именно там появилась поддержка JSON. Для более старых - надо будет извращаться. И извращаться сильно.

Соответственно, записать куда-то из триггера - надо этой функции передать нужное JSON-значение через NEW или OLD псевдостроки.

```
INSERT INTO new_table SET new_tablecol = JSON_LENGTH(NEW.content);
```

Вот так, если я верно понял, какой именно элемент надо считать.